# How to save variable acquired from method for later use in Java?

Tags: java, sql, variables

I have 3 classes, Main, Pin, and Employee. (More classes to be added in the future)

The Main class runs a program that prompts use to enter an password from a method in the Pin class. The password is sent using SQL to a database to be verified from methods in the Employee and Pin classes. If the password matches, it returns back the ID of that employee.

The problem I am having is saving the ID. I retrieved the ID, but I want to be able to use this ID for the rest of the program. I want to save it in the Employee class but it is returned in a method from the Pin class. How would I be able to save this ID to be used by the Employee class, or any class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, if I understand you correctly you may want something like a composition of Employee and Pin?

```
Employee e = ...

e.setPin(pin);
```

Or is the problem, that you don't know how to assign a specific pin to an Employee, so that it is still assigned to the Employee in the next run of your application?

UPDATE: After receiving more information: You need to create an application context for your program. As it seems to be a standalone application with one user at a time, this can be a static field in some class.

If the application is a multi-user application, then the context needs to be static per user.

If the application is a web-application, then your application scope is the `Session`, that will be terminated during Logout. (That is actually not precise, as the session is the session scope, and the application scope is really the context of the application. But in your case, the pin is session scoped.)

A sample for a standalone/single user application:

```
public class ApplicationContext {

    static ApplicationContext CTX;
    public static ApplicationContext get() {
        if( CTX == null ) {
            CTX = new ApplicationContext();
        }
        return CTX;
    }

    private Pin pin;
    public Pin getPin() { return pin; }
    public void setPin(Pin pin) { this.pin = pin; }

    // ... add more stuff here ...

    public void logout() {
        CTX = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I did. I added a setter and getter. But I think the problem is that when I use the setter inside a method in my employee class, it doesn't save what is returned. It just returns 0. The main class calls a method in the pin class which calls a method in the employee class. How do I print out the variable returned from the method that retrieves the ID in the employee class in the main class?

Comment: The pin should be saved for the entire duration the program is running until the logout button is pressed, which restarts the program. The purpose is to use the pin to access the sql database whenever we need information about the employee and their transaction history. For example, when we successfully log in, the employee class will ask for the employee's position, "cook", "cashier", "manager", which sends the id to the database to find the position based on the id. The position is returned and the interface is set up based on the level of authority.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a concept of a so called application scoped object.
There are various libraries that work with JavaEE but I assume you're using Java SE.
[DeltaSpike](http://deltaspike.apache.org/external.html) of apache allows to do such scoped beans within Java SE, too. See [an example](https://github.com/os890/javase-cdi-ds-project-template/tree/master/src/main/java/org/os890/cdi/template). Like this, you can create an @ApplicationScoped bean where you can store values across your application.

Please know that there are other scopes possible, such as SessionScoped(HTTP), WindowsScoped(BrowserWindow) etc.

This example shall point you to the right direction but there might be better approaches than to use the application scoped in your case.